# Intel 82576 Ethernet Controller stuck at 10Mb/s

Tags: networking, drivers, intel, ethernet

I have a server board which uses the Intel 82576 network controller.  When I plug it into my gigabit switch it auto configures a link speed of 10Mb/s.

```
$ sudo ethtool eth0
Supported ports: [ TP ]
Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                        100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                        1000baseT/Full 
Supported pause frame use: Symmetric
Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
Advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                        100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                        1000baseT/Full 
Advertised pause frame use: Symmetric
Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
Speed: 10Mb/s
Duplex: Full
Port: Twisted Pair
PHYAD: 1
Transceiver: internal
Auto-negotiation: on
MDI-X: on (auto)
Supports Wake-on: pumbg
Wake-on: g
Current message level: 0x00000007 (7)
               drv probe link
Link detected: yes
```

Things I have tried:

- Installing the latest drivers from intel. Download, unpack, make install, rmmod, modprobe, update-initramfs. dmesg says they are loaded.

  ```
  [   11.112784] Intel(R) Gigabit Ethernet Network Driver - version 5.2.15
  [   11.308017] igb 0000:01:00.0: Intel(R) Gigabit Ethernet Network Connection
  [   11.497794] igb 0000:01:00.1: Intel(R) Gigabit Ethernet Network Connection
  ```
- Checking the cable.  Its cat5e and my laptop connects to the switch with 1Gb/s through the same cable.
- Connecting the server to my laptop directly.  It configures with 1Gb/s.  This in particular seemed really weird to me.  I tried it again with another computer; it also showed 1Gb/s.  The only thing its having trouble with is the switch.

UPDATE:

- It successfully negotiates 100Mb/s with a 100Mb/s switch by the same company. (Zonet)
- I tried `ethtool -s eth0 advertise 0x020` which only advertises 1Gb full duplex.  It won't connect at all when I do this.

UPDATE2:

- Cards that can successfully negotiate gigabit with the switch do not advertise pause frame use, which the 82576 does.  I wonder if this has something to do with it.  I have tried disabling pause frames, but maybe I am doing it wrong?

Comment: what catagory of ethernet wire you using. If you chose cat3, it could affect that process into going into 10mb/s

Comment: So far I've tried cat 5e and cat 6.

Comment: Use Cat 6 and manually fix the network speed on both the switch and the card to 1GBps.  What does this do?